# My react multiselect doesn't empty after uploading my form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've used the multiselect react dropdown to assign multiple categories to a product in an e-commerce project. But when I upload the product form, all other inputs are empty except for the multiselect. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

This is what I've got so far:

```
<div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Category</label>
            {Array.isArray(props.categories) && (
              <Multiselect
                options={props.categories}
                displayValue="name"
                onSelect={handlerOnChangeCategory}
                onRemove={handlerOnChangeCategory}
              />
            )}
          </div>
```

And this is what I got in the handlerOnChangeCategory function:

```
  function handlerOnChangeCategory(event) {
    const idArray = event.map((e) => {
      return e.id;
    });
    setProduct({
      ...product,
      category: idArray,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for what you've done, and do so with a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I've already updated the question